# igraph assign a vector as an attribute for a vertex

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to assign a vector as an attribute for a vertex, but without any luck:

```
# assignment of a numeric value (everything is ok)
g<-set.vertex.attribute(g, 'checked', 2, 3)
V(g)$checked
```

.

```
# assignment of a vector (is not working)
g<-set.vertex.attribute(g, 'checked', 2, c(3, 1))
V(g)$checked
```

checking the manual, http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/attributes.html
it looks like this is not possible. Is there any workaround?

Up till now the only things I come up with are:

store this

- information in another structure
- convert vector to a string with delimiters and store as a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine:

```
## replace c(3,1) by list(c(3,1))
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, 'checked', 2, list(c(3, 1)))
V(g)[2]$checked
[1] 3 1
```

**EDIT** Why this works?
When you use :

```
    g<-set.vertex.attribute(g, 'checked', 2, c(3, 1))
```

You get this warning :

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Indeed you try to put c(3,1) which has a **length** =2 in a variable with length =1. SO the idea is to replace c(3,1) with something similar but with length =1.  For example:

```
 length(list(c(3,1)))
[1] 1
> length(data.frame(c(3,1)))
[1] 1
```